# Codeigniter form action issue

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i just have written some form in codeigniter and i have one error/issue that is not familiar to me.(I will post the code) When i click on button "Generate" redirect me to page http://localhost/rabota/inv.bg/invoiceGenerator/?selectedID=1 (1 is selected id), but it must redirect me to http://localhost/rabota/inv.bg/invoiceGenerator/?id=3&selectedID=1
so ?id=3 is missing.

First id get's from database, but it's not important where it get's it, important is it's not in link but it must be.
When i go to source code it outputs me action="http://localhost/rabota/inv.bg/invoiceGenerator/?id=3215&" what is correct i think?

Form code

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo base_url();?>invoiceGenerator/?id=<?php echo $o['id']; ?>&" class="trackForm clearfix">
<div class="btn-group btn-block"><center>
<select id="what_is_c" name="selectedID" class="form-control col-md-4 pull-right" value="0"  style="width: 50% !important">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn green btn-sm">Generate</button>
</div>
</td>
</form>
```

Comment: use hidden field example `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $o['id']; ?>" />`

Comment: Thank's Magesh it helps me :)